# How to use Angular/Typescript to Access Nested Array from HTTP data?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http

I am sending JSON from a NodeJS API to an Angular app to be displayed as part of an Angular component. The returned data is simple Mongo id and name string. The data is present in debugger and Postman like so:

```
    {  "httpAllNames": [
{
  "_id": "5d5c54315be61d26c0b2afb8",
  "campaignTitle": "Make America Zombie Free Again"
},
{
  "_id": "5d5c54735be61d26c0b2afba",
  "campaignTitle": "Zmobie Free 2"
},
{
  "_id": "5d5d3fb280dead0604fe6f8c",
  "campaignTitle": "Universal Basic Income For All"
},
{
  "_id": "5d5eeaee3278d24b10093988",
  "campaignTitle": "Remove All Zombies from the US"
}  ]}
```

I pass the data from my Campaign Service to the component without any trouble. The code in question for accessing it within the browseCampaigns.component is as follows:

```
    browsingCampaignNames: httpAllNames[];
    campaignCountDisplayed: number = 0;

      onLoadCampaigns() {
          this.browsCampServ.fetchCampaignsForBrowsing().subscribe(camps => {
      this.browsingCampaignNames = camps;
         });
        this.campaignCountDisplayed = this.browsingCampaignNames.length;
      }
```

What I'm expecting is to have an array of as many items as are within the httpAllNames object, however, Angular is treating that as a single array, with the desired array nested within.

I guess what I'm trying to do is 'unwrap' the outer layer so that my `browsingCampaignNames` property is able to access it.

I've tried adjusting the output of the API by removing the status code and unwrapping it from a generic `httpResponse` object. I've also tried `this.browsingCampaignNames = camps[0];`  and `this.browsingCampaignNames = camps['httpAllNames'];` as though to try to access the data by index, even though those methods are 'hacky.'

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The object you are returning contains one property "httpAllNames", and this property contains the array. You would have to do camps["httpAllNames"] or have the api just send the array without the property. So if the api is doing something like res.send(result); you would need to change that to res.send(result.httpAllNames);

Comment: Thanks man. I pulled the {} off of my http response to just send the raw data and it worked out.